# Another versions of squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have two questions regarding squeeze theorem:

1.Can I use squeeze theorem in higher dimensions? (I'm almost sure yes)

2. If we have the strict inequality: $x_n\lt z_n\lt y_n$ when $\lim x_n=\lim y_n= L$, what can I say about $\lim z_n$? $\lim z_n=L$?

Thanks

Comment: 1. When is a vector larger than another? Or did you mean componentwise (in which case the answer is trivial). 2. Yes.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen For 1., I think $f\colon U \to \mathbb{R}$, when $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Ahh. Makes sense, Daniel!